# SignalR and Ninject - Ninject not returning a controller for the route

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ninject, signalr

I'm trying to set up SignalR in an existing ASP.Net MVC 4 project that uses Ninject for DI, however whenever I try and access the SignalR default route (which I have confirmed is in the route table), I get the following exception thrown:

```
Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Infrastructure.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'signalr'.
```

I have tried injecting the Ninject kernel into SignalR via:

```
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver = new NinjectSignalRDependencyResolver(ninjectKernel);
```

And I am setting the default routes via:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

in Global.asax Application_Start

I can't seem to find any way to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, resolved it myself - it was not a ninject issue, it was a routing order issue.

I needed the ~/signalr route to be higher up in the routing table order, which meant shifting the RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs(); entry to the top of my Application_Start, above the RegisterRoutes call.